# PoE AP is powered up but line protocol is down

Tags: cisco, access-point, power-over-ethernet

The distance between AP and the switch is around 60 meters. The AP is powered up and SSIDs are broadcasted. But the Ethernet interface has line Protocol down. I have changed the RJ45 connectors on both side of the cable but still same behaviour.

Is this related to the cable length?

Comment: PoE is supposed to be good for 100 meters. Is this that 3702I AP? I think that requires PoE+.

Comment: You've changed connectors - but have you **actually tested** the cable? This smells most like a cable problem, from afar.

Comment: 3700's will work on PoE, just with reduced performance. Where are you seeing the line protocol down, on the switch or the AP or both? Also to clarify, is the interface up but line protocol down. Or are they both down?

Comment: Whats the AP model and switch series? If your switch supports it, try to perform a tdr test in the switchport. That's for the beginning of your troubleshooting. If you see dodgy figures call in your cabler. Do you have a known good working AP to test the cabling if the tdr test is good?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If the SSID is broadcasting then the AP is clearly powered up and PoE is working. Line Protocol Down indicates that Ethernet is not functioning on the link. This could be caused by

- Speed/Duplex mismatch
- Faulty cable
- Bad switchport
- other configuration issues

It is unlikely that it has to do with cable length. Good luck!